# On click action not working properly

Tags: javascript, php

My javascript function

```
   function ConfirmDelete()
      {
            if (confirm("Delete Account?"))
             var id= $(this).attr('data-id');
             alert(id);
                 location.href='config-project-delete.php?id='+id;
      }
```

onclick event trigger

```
<?php
echo "<span  onclick=\"ConfirmDelete()\" data-id={$row['project_id']}  class='button-content'>
<i class='glyph-icon icon-trash-o float-left'></i>
Delete
</span>
</div>
</a>
</li>"; ?>
```

I cant able to get the data-id.It keep saying undefined.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `this` doesn't refer to the element where you called the function, but rather refers to the owner of the function (which, as you've defined it, looks like it's in the global scope).  So you'd have to call the function with the parameter of the value you want, then use it within the function, as such:

```
<?php
echo "<span  onclick=\"ConfirmDelete(\$(this).attr('data-id'))\" data-id={$row['project_id']}  class='button-content'>
...
```

(The `$` is escaped because you're echoing it with PHP).

And then your function would look something like this:

```
function ConfirmDelete(data_id)
  {
        if (confirm("Delete Account?"))
         var id= data_id;
         alert(id);
             location.href='config-project-delete.php?id='+id;
  }
```

If you aren't using the data-id attribute anywhere else and only for this purpose, you can simplify the HTML side as well by passing the value directly:

```
<?php
echo "<span  onclick=\"ConfirmDelete('{$row['project_id']}')\" class='button-content'>
...
```

Note that I haven't tested any of this code, and when mixing HTML, JS, and PHP, it can be easy to screw this up (at least for me), so tweak the above as needed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<span onclick="javascript:deleteConfirm('<?php echo 'config-project-delete.php?id='.$row['project_id'] ?>');" deleteConfirm class='button-content'>
```

javascript

```
function deleteConfirm(url)
 {
    if(confirm('Do you want to Delete this record ?'))
    {
        window.location.href=url;
    }
 }
```

Comment: onclick doesn't need to call to `javascript:` URI scheme. You only need to if you use the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the triggering object to your function.

```
   function ConfirmDelete(triggering_object)
      {
            if (confirm("Delete Account?")) {
                var id= $(triggering_object).attr('data-id');
                alert(id);
                location.href='config-project-delete.php?id='+id;
            }
      }
```

And add the 'this' to your object:

```
echo "<span  onclick=\"ConfirmDelete(this);\" data-id={$row['project_id']}  class='button-content'>";
```

Comment: `this` will return the window, what you are looking for is `event` to be the passed parameter.

Comment: Actually he's looking for the triggering span, because he wants to pass the triggering spans's attribute to the function..

Answer (score 0):

Although Nick Coons answer is an easier way to do this (pass the variable to the function), to get the results you first asked about using the data attribute method, you have to pass `event` to the function to get the proper node. http://jsfiddle.net/2t4hK/

```
function ConfirmDelete(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (confirm("Delete Account?")) {
        var id = target.attr('data-id');
        alert(id);
        //location.href='config-project-delete.php?id='+id;
    }
}

<span onclick="ConfirmDelete(event)" data-id="1"  class="button-content">Delete</span>

<?php
   echo '<span onclick="ConfirmDelete(event)" data-id="'.$row['project_id'].'" class="button-content">';
   echo '<i class="glyph-icon icon-trash-o float-left"></i>Delete</span>';
?>
```

Also, in your code, I suggest you wrap the value for data-id inside of quotes.